# Cosmos DB select where objects

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have a list of defined objects:

```
[{"name":"name1", "age":25}, {"name":"name2", "age":27}]
```

and I would like to return records that are the same

Is there any way in Cosmos DB to perform the following query?

```
select * from c
where c in ({"name":"name1", "age":25}, {"name":"name2", "age":27})
```

my records are like this:

```
[
   {
      "name":"name1",
      "age":25,
      "height":165
   },
   {
      "name":"name2",
      "age":27,
      "height":169
   },
   {
      "name":"name3",
      "age":35,
      "height":185
   }
]
```

The query would return this result:

```
[
   {
      "name":"name1",
      "age":25,
      "height":165
   },
   {
      "name":"name2",
      "age":27,
      "height":169
   }
]
```

Comment: You always want to filter these 2 objects or you have more?

Comment: @Sajeetharan more, this list is dynamic, it can be 1 or N

Comment: @Passella You can try this SQL: SELECT * FROM c where ARRAY_CONTAINS([{"name":"name1", "age":25}, {"name":"name2", "age":27}],{"name":c.name,"age":c.age})

Comment: @SteveZhao It worked! put as an answer please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`ARRAY_CONTAINS`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/sql-query-array-contains)

```
SELECT * FROM c where ARRAY_CONTAINS([{"name":"name1", "age":25}, {"name":"name2", "age":27}],{"name":c.name,"age":c.age})
```

[image]

Note : Might be useful for others as in the comment.